# Is there a no activity timeout delay with MVC running on Windows Azure with the SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have a new application with no users. I know the first time when I publish to Azure there's a delay as code is compiled.  However after the application has been used if I try to access it again in about 30 minutes it seems very slow initially and faster once I have accessed it. My application using MVC4 and connects to a SQL Server for login authentication.

Is there some timeout or delay? Does the service go into a sleep mode to be woken up when used  for a while?

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS shuts down the application pool after 20 minutes of inactivity in order to conserve server resources.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx

Now, to make things more interesting on Azure, as far as I know, you cannot configure this setting from the web.config file of your application, but rather either through the UI, command line or machine.config file.  But there is hope!

**This is assuming that you are using web/worker roles and not the new Web Sites thing they came out with**

You have to create a startup task for your web role that will do the IIS configuration for you.  Its a simple batch file that you instruct the web role to run on startup.  [There is more information here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/controlling-application-pool-idle-timeouts-in-windows-azure) but basically the .cmd file would look something like this:

```
REM *** This keeps this file from running on your local emulator. 
if "%EMULATED%"=="true" goto :EOF

REM *** Prevent the IIS app pools from shutting down due to being idle. 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00

REM *** Prevent IIS app pool recycles from recycling on the default schedule of 1740 minutes (29 hours). 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00
```

And in your serviceDefintion.csdef file, add the following schema element (assuming you placed the file in a startup folder of your web application and named it disableTimeout.cmd):

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="startup\disableTimeout.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>
```

Remember, there can be good reasons to recycle and idle timeout your application pool, but they can be adjusted if you have  low traffic site to not happen so frequently.